# sql - ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00937

```
 select
    location,
    home_team_name,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' and extract(month from match_date)=1 then 1 end) january_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' and extract(month from match_date)=2 then 1 end) february_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' and extract(month from match_date)=3 then 1 end) march_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' then 1 end) Total
from match_results

union all

select 
    'total' as location,
    'total' as home_team_name,
    count(case when extract(month from match_date)=1 then 1 end) january_2018,
    count(case when extract(month from match_date)=2 then 1 end) february_2018,
    count(case when extract(month from match_date)=3 then 1 end) march_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' then 1 end) Total
from match_results
group by location,home_team_name;
```

Error message: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function. Currently running this on oracle live SQL.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Move the `group by` to the first select. And have a look at `grouping sets` to get both in a single select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running an aggregate query, every non-aggregated column must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. You have two `UNION`ed subquery : and only the first one has non-aggregated columns (namely, `location` and `home_team`), however you happened to put the `GROUP BY` clause in the second one, that, as it seems to compute totals, probably does not need one. You could just place the `GROUP BY` clause in the first query instead of the second :

```
select
    location,
    home_team_name,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' and extract(month from match_date)=1 then 1 end) january_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' and extract(month from match_date)=2 then 1 end) february_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' and extract(month from match_date)=3 then 1 end) march_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' then 1 end) Total
from match_results
group by location,home_team_name

union all

select 
    'total' as location,
    'total' as home_team_name,
    count(case when extract(month from match_date)=1 then 1 end) january_2018,
    count(case when extract(month from match_date)=2 then 1 end) february_2018,
    count(case when extract(month from match_date)=3 then 1 end) march_2018,
    count(case when extract(year from match_date)='2018' then 1 end) Total
from match_results
;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I really appreciate

Answer (score 3):

I recommend `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(location, 'Total') as location,
       coalesce(home_team_name, 'Total') as home_team_name,
       sum(case when match_date >= date '2018-01-01' and 
                     match_date < date '2018-02-01'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as january_2018,
       sum(case when match_date >= date '2018-02-01' and 
                     match_date < date '2018-03-01'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as february_2018,
       sum(case when match_date >= date '2018-03-01' and 
                     match_date < date '2018-04-01'
                then 1 else 0
           end) as march_2018,
       sum(case when match_date >= date '2018-01-01' and 
                     match_date < date '2019-01-01'
               then 1 else 0
           end) as total_2018
from match_results
group by grouping sets ( (location, home_team_name), () );
```

That is, repeating the query is unnecessary.  I also changed the date comparisons to use actual dates.  I find this more readable and maintainable than extracting date parts.

Comment: @sammywemmy . . . I find it surprising that you prefer the more verbose solution.

Comment: I learnt a lot from both answers and understand sql more .it isn’t one over the other, I can only tick off one answer tho