# Modify Select Statement To Sum Single Field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery

I have the below select statement that has extracted all the data I need, but I am trying to modify it so that the REJECTS by SHIFT by PROD_DATE are summed.

```
SELECT B.PROD_DATE,B.SHIFT,B.REJECTS
FROM REJECTS B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIST_ILLUM_PART C ON B.HIST_ILLUM_PART_ID = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIST_ILLUM_RT A ON A.ID = C.HIST_ILLUM_RT_ID
WHERE
B. REJECT_CODE NOT in ('START','SETUP','QC')
AND B.PROD_DATE >= SYSDATE - 8
ORDER BY SHIFT, PROD_DATE
```

I have tried

```
   SELECT B.PROD_DATE,B.SHIFT,SUM(B.REJECTS)
```

I recieve the following error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Do I need a subquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql - ORA-00937: not a single-group group function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159404/sql-ora-00937-not-a-single-group-group-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a GROUP BY clause to your query when doing aggregations. In pseudocode it means for each distinct group of B.PROD_DATE and B.SHIFT get the sum of all B.REJECTS for that set,

```
SELECT B.PROD_DATE,B.SHIFT,SUM(B.REJECTS) AS REJECTS
FROM REJECTS B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIST_ILLUM_PART C ON B.HIST_ILLUM_PART_ID = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIST_ILLUM_RT A ON A.ID = C.HIST_ILLUM_RT_ID
WHERE
B. REJECT_CODE NOT in ('START','SETUP','QC')
AND B.PROD_DATE >= SYSDATE - 8
GROUP BY B.PROD_DATE,B.SHIFT
ORDER BY SHIFT, PROD_DATE
```